# Is it possible to change style.css file dynamically in phonegap app?

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

my app has **two themes** and i want to change them dynamically.

Is it possible to change **style.css** file **dynamically** ? if yes then how?

Please help.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Instead of changing dynamically, why dont you hold two seperate css classes and load it through jquery/JS depending on the one you need. Here's a nice article on the concept http://www.thesitewizard.com/javascripts/change-style-sheets.shtml

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know it's not possible

But, there could be solution for that: use CSS classes with slightly different names, like ClassName_css1 and ClassName_css2

And you could use jquery o pure javascript to swap element class